# Vb.net Save data from datagridview to txt and load it

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, save, load

i'am new programmer and just studying about Visual Basic, and to complete my exams
The Data i have

> Tool_1 screwdriver
>   Tool_2 screw
>   Tool_3 Magnet

And many more
i've create project, it have Data Grid View(two columns, Tools & Names) and two Button(btSave & btOpen)
i just try it with this code

```
Private Sub btSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btSave.Click
SaveGridData(DataGridView1, ThisFilename)
End Sub
    Private Sub SaveGridData(ByRef ThisGrid As DataGridView, ByVal Filename As String)
        ThisGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText
        ThisGrid.SelectAll()
        IO.File.WriteAllText(Filename, ThisGrid.GetClipboardContent().GetText.TrimEnd)
        ThisGrid.ClearSelection()
    End Sub
    Private Sub btOpen_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btOpen.Click
    LoadGridData(DataGridView1, ThisFilename)
End Sub

Private Sub LoadGridData(ByRef ThisGrid As DataGridView, ByVal Filename As String)
        ThisGrid.Rows.Clear()
        For Each THisLine In My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Filename).Split(Environment.NewLine)
            ThisGrid.Rows.Add(Split(THisLine, " "))
        Next
    End Sub
```

When i save the file it's no problem the txt file is ok, but when i want to load Text "Tool_1 Screwdriver" is not split but is in "Tools" Column
there is a solution to this ?

Comment: try using a separator like comma or something and save the file, so when you try to load it. it will be easy to split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this insetad of your loop in loadgriddata

```
For Each THisLine In My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Filename).Split(Environment.NewLine)
dim str as string()
str=thisline.split(" ")
ThisGrid.Rows.Add(str(0),str(1))
Next
```

hope it helps.

Comment: it's error in 
str = thisline.split(" ") 
Error Message "Error 1 Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'String'."

Answer (score 0):

Hey I struggled with this aswell, but I have some usefull code:

export listview:

```
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\RS Account Maker\Accounts" & "\")
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Dim Path As String = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim AllItems As String = ""

    Try

        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
            AllItems = AllItems & item.Text & "#" & item.SubItems(1).Text & "#" & item.SubItems(2).Text & vbNewLine
        Next

        AllItems = AllItems.Trim

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try


    Try
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Path) Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Path)
        End If

        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Path, AllItems, False)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error" & vbNewLine & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error ")
    End Try
```

import listview:

```
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Dim Path As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim AllItems As String



    Try
        AllItems = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Path)

        Dim ItemLines As New TextBox
        ItemLines.Text = AllItems


        For Each line As String In ItemLines.Lines

            Dim a1() As String = line.Split("#")

            Dim ItemName As String = a1(0)
            Dim SubItem1 As String = a1(1)
            Dim SubItem2 As String = a1(2)

            Dim Item As New ListViewItem(ItemName)

            Item.SubItems.Add(SubItem1)
            Item.SubItems.Add(SubItem2)

            ListView1.Items.AddRange(New ListViewItem() {Item})

        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error" & vbNewLine & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error ")
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line is wrong.

```
ThisGrid.Rows.Add(Split(THisLine, " "))
```

The above code was amended as follows.

```
Dim ThisFilename As String = Application.StartupPath & "\MyData.dat"

    Private Sub butSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        SaveGridData(Datagrid1, ThisFilename)

    End Sub

    Private Sub butLoad_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        LoadGridData(Datagrid1, ThisFilename)

    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveGridData(ByRef ThisGrid As DataGridView, ByVal Filename As String)

        ThisGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText

        ThisGrid.SelectAll()

        IO.File.WriteAllText(Filename, ThisGrid.GetClipboardContent().GetText.TrimEnd)

        ThisGrid.ClearSelection()

    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadGridData(ByRef ThisGrid As DataGridView, ByVal Filename As String)

        ThisGrid.Rows.Clear()

        For Each THisLine In My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Filename).Split(Environment.NewLine)

            ThisGrid.Rows.Add(Split(THisLine, ControlChars.Tab))

        Next

    End Sub
```